# How do I make Puppeteer only click selector with a set "status"?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, puppeteer

I am trying to make a bot to help me buy tickets but, as the picture shows, only a few seats are available.

I have a problem to work out how to make Puppeteer only click the available seats.

In the picture below, there are a lot of sold seats and some available ones. In the developer tools to the right side in the picture I can easily separate the sold seats from the available ones by looking at the `data-status="available"` part.

I have managed to make the bot click every seat, but not to only click the green ones. If possible, I also only want it to click a couple of green ones, and not all of them, 3 to 4 would be perfect.

[Image of available seats: due to low reputation I have to link the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jOox.png)

The code I have for clicking the seats looks like this (and keeps going until it has clicked all the seats):

```js
    await page.waitForSelector("#arena > div > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1)"
    await page.click ("#arena > div > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1)"), elem => elem.click();
    await delay(10);
    await page.click ("#arena > div > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2)"), elem => elem.click();
    await delay(10);
    await page.click ("#arena > div > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(3)"), elem => elem.click();
    await delay(10);
    await page.click ("#arena > div > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(4)"), elem => elem.click();
    await delay(10);
    await page.click ("#arena > div > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(5)"), elem => elem.click();
```

I want it to click the seats with the value `data-status="available"`

I added `await delay` because there is a pop up that fades in when you have to "confirm seat" which I will be implementing later, as I feel that should be fairly easy.

How do I make Puppeteer only click available seats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting those seats by the data attribute:

```js
await page.$$eval(
  '.tc-section--seat[data-status="available"]',
  els => els.forEach(e => e.click())
);
```

Maybe use `#arena .tc-section--seat[data-status="available"]` if there are other sections that you need to disambiguate.

Alternately, if you want to use trusted Puppeteer clicks:

```js
const seatEls = await page.$$('.tc-section--seat[data-status="available"]');

for (const el of seatEls) {
  await el.click();
}
```

I suggest steering clear of those [browser generated selectors](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors). They're simultaneously too specific and vague at the same time (not using a clear-cut class or data attribute, instead using a giant rigidly-specified tree of plain tag names).

Comment: Thanks, selecting seats by the data attribute worked like a charm! Do you know if there's any way to make it select only a set number of seats, 5 for example?

Comment: You mean the first 5 of the available seats, seat number 5 of all seats if it's available or the 5th of the available seats? It's hard to say without seeing the HTML, but once you have `seatEls`, you can grab the first 5 with `seatEls.slice(0, 5)` then loop as shown or grab the 5th available with `seaEls[4].click()`. If you want the 5th seat of all of them if it's available, maybe use `.tc-section--seat`  selector on all of them and index the 4th or try `.tc-section--seat[data-status="available"]` and check if it has the `data-status="available"` attribute before clicking.

Comment: I want it to select any 5 available seats whether it be the first 5 or last 5 or any inbetween. I think the `seatEls.slice(0, 5)` is the right command. Thank you!